# Spyder keeps crashing during load in all Anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

I was running python 2.7 in Anaconda2 in spyder 4 up until today with no problems. But now I keep getting the same  error, when I make an environment and install python 2.7 and spyder in it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3718, in main
> mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3557, in run_spyder
> main = MainWindow(options)
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 426, in **init**
> from spyder.preferences.runconfig import RunConfigPage
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/preferences  /runconfig.py", line 482, in 
> class RunConfigPage(GeneralConfigPage):
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/preferences/runconfig.py", line 487, in RunConfigPage
> ICON = ima.icon('run')
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/icon_manager.py", line 394, in icon
> directory=_resource['directory'])
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtawesome/**init**.py", line 178, in load_font
> return _instance().load_font(prefix, ttf_filename, charmap_filename, directory)
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtawesome/**init**.py", line 54, in _instance
> 'materialdesignicons-webfont-charmap.json')
> File "/home/cmiprc/anaconda2/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtawesome/iconic_font.py", line 206, in **init**
> super().**init**()
> TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

This started happening after I reinstalled the package "pydicom" in the environment, and now nothing works. I have reinstalled anaconda2, used `spyder --reset`, and all other common suggestions.

Spyder 3.3.6 works in the base environment, but every time I make a new environment and install spyder in this, I get the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem, you need to install QtAwesome **0.7.3** in your environment. For that, please use the following command:

```
conda install qtawesome=0.7.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to answer Carlos! This solves the problem with running Spyder under the said conditions. Is there a way, where I don't have to do this every time I make a new environment? I also still get errors from the pydicom package, so it seems that something more else has changed somewhere. Any clues to help me?

Comment: We're going to release Spyder 4.1.6 with its dependencies fixed for Python 2 in a few days.

Comment: 0.7.3 is not available for me, but 0.7.2 appears to be working.